# param is missing or the value is empty: conversation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

This is a followup to this thread: [Ruby on Rails: found unpermitted parameters: _method, authenticity_token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089902/ruby-on-rails-found-unpermitted-parameters-method-authenticity-token)

I have the following line: `<%= button_to 'Message me', conversations_path(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: @user.id), class: 'btn btn-primary m-t' %>`

But when I click on the button, I get the error: `param is missing or the value is empty: conversation`.

I can see that `conversation` is not in the params hash: `{"authenticity_token"=>"r5pwStXl6NwEgqqq0GT0RQxCqsGHrTVsh4Q7HviX+re5k+XOs2ioRv9kZqvDGz9Ch/6O6D1nOMjscquHQJlB+g==", "recipient_id"=>"1", "sender_id"=>"2", "controller"=>"conversations", "action"=>"create"}`

As suggested in the other thread, it was helpful to add `require(:conversation)` to the controller:

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /conversations
  # GET /conversations.json
  def index
    @users = User.all

    # Restrict to conversations with at least one message and sort by last updated
    @conversations = Conversation.joins(:messages).uniq.order('updated_at DESC')
  end

  # POST /conversations
  # POST /conversations.json
  def create
    if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).present?
      @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).first
    else
      @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
    end

    redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def conversation_params
      params.require(:conversation).permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id)
    end
end
```

This worked for a while, but it has for some reason stopped working. How should I fix this? And why did it stop working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding 'conversation' manually to the hash seems to work: `<%= button_to 'Message me', conversations_path(conversation: { sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: @user.id }), class: 'btn btn-primary m-t' %>`.

I also had to fix the controller to take into account the nesting:

```
def create
  if Conversation.between(params[:conversation][:sender_id], params[:conversation][:recipient_id]).present?
    @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:conversation][:sender_id], params[:conversation][:recipient_id]).first
  else
    @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
  end

  redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
end
```